# allure index.html gives indefinite loading

Tags: report, allure

Let me put in a step by step manner to explain my problem:

1. Once the Automation Test Execution is completed I get `report/allure-results` folder
2. and then with the help of follow up command `allure generate --clean report/allure-results` I am able to get `allure-report` folder.
3. Now next step is to zip the folder `allure-report` and send it to team members via email.

The issue is: When they open `index.html` they get to see Loading for an indefinite time. Results never load up.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try opening the `index.html` in edge (other than chrome).

Comment: Have you tried? Did it work for you? I am using Mac Catalina and I have tried in Chrome, Firefox, Safari but same issue.

Comment: Yes, I had the same issue on chrome but was able to load it in Edge. Btw, you can generate the report in site folder and then zip it so that you can open the report in Edge (other than chrome) successfully.

Comment: Did anyone manage to solve this ? I am facing this in all 3 browsers chrome, Firefox and Edge.

Answer (score 1):

Workaround for Firefox: open `about:config` and change `privacy.file_unique_origin` to `false`